# Override behavior of a stubbed function using JEST not working as expected

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a test class that tests behavior of various HTTP methods in a Nest controller class. I am using Jest manual mocks to stub the behavior of various functions in the service class so that I do not have to rely on actual dependencies/services, eg. snowflake. I have a top level jest.mock() defined as follows which initializes the mocked version of the service class instead of the actual service class.The mocked service class is created inside **mocks** folder adjacent to the actual service class.
I am redefining the behavior of one of the mocked functions in the 'error scenario' describe block as shown in the code snippet below, for testing the error scenario . The test scenario : 'throws an error' is failing as it is still picking up the default mocked behavior. Any pointers or help is appreciated.

In short, I want to be able to define different mocked behavior for a single function of the same mocked class for various test scenarios.

Thanks

```
jest.mock('@modules/shipment-summary/shipment-summary.service');

describe('ShipmentSummaryController', () => {
  let shipmentSummaryController: ShipmentSummaryController;
  let shipmentSummaryService: ShipmentSummaryService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [ShipmentSummaryController],
      providers: [ShipmentSummaryService],
    }).compile();

    shipmentSummaryController = moduleRef.get<ShipmentSummaryController>(
      ShipmentSummaryController,
    );
    shipmentSummaryService = moduleRef.get<ShipmentSummaryService>(
      ShipmentSummaryService,
    );
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  //All the tests inside this describe block work as expected
  describe('valid shipment-mode scenario', () => {
      describe('valid shipment modes for tenant', () => {
      let modes: ShipmentMode[];
      beforeEach(async () => {
        modes = await shipmentSummaryController.getAllShipmentModes('256');
      });

      test('calls the service fn. with the correct arg', () => {
        expect(shipmentSummaryService.getAvailableShipmentModes).toBeCalledWith(
          '256',
        );
      });

      test('all available shipment modes for 256 are returned', () => {
        expect(modes).toEqual(validModeDropdown());
      });
    });
  });

// redefining behavior of getAllshipmentModes() is not working
    describe('error scenario', () => {
        let modes: ShipmentMode[] = []
        beforeEach(async () => {
            modes = await shipmentSummaryController.getAllShipmentModes('256');
          });
        
        beforeAll(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
            jest.mock('@modules/shipment-summary/shipment-summary.service.ts', () => {
                return {
                    getAvailableShipmentModes: () => {
                        throw new Error('Test error');
                    }, 
                }  
            });
        });
        
        test('throws an error', () => {
            expect(() => shipmentSummaryController.getAllShipmentModes('256')).toThrow();
        })
    })
});
```

My mocked service class is as follows:

```
export const ShipmentSummaryService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    
    // Fn. to be mocked differently per test scenario.
    getAvailableShipmentModes: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(validModeDropdown()),

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of accomplishing this. The [Nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing) outline a number of them. However, one of my preferred ways, `useValue`, is not as clear as it could be, so I'll added it here.

This example will also use `jest` in order to spy on a mock, changing its behavior depending on the test.

1. Imagine these two simple resources

```js
Injectable();
export class SimpleService {
  public sayHello(): string {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
}

@Controller()
export class SimpleController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SimpleService) private readonly simpleService: SimpleService
  ) {}

  @Get()
  public controllerSaysHello(): string {
    return this.simpleService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

2. Your tests could look something like this

```js
describe("SimpleController", () => {
  let controller: SimpleController;

  const mockReturnValue = "Goodbye, world..",
    mockSimpleService: SimpleService = {
      sayHello: () => mockReturnValue,
    };

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SimpleController,
        { provide: SimpleService, useValue: mockSimpleService },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get(SimpleController);
  });

  test("default mockSimpleService", () => {
    const result = controller.controllerSaysHello();

    expect(result).toBe(mockReturnValue);
  });

  test("spied on mockSimpleService", () => {
    const differentReturnValue = "Hallo!";

    jest
      .spyOn(mockSimpleService, "sayHello")
      .mockReturnValue(differentReturnValue);

    const result = controller.controllerSaysHello();

    expect(result).toBe(differentReturnValue);
  });
});
```